# Deleting all occurrences of an element from a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, tuples

How would I remove all occurrences in a list of tuples where the second element in the tuple is repeated?

I have:

```
a = [('a',1),('b',3),('c',1),('d',1),('e',5),('f',1)]
```

I am trying to return

```
[('b',3),('e',5)]
```

I tried

```
a = list(set(a))
```

But doesn't remove all occurrences, is there a way to do that without importing any libraries?

Comment: Do you have any code that you've tried? This website is more for help with code errors, not writing the code

Comment: Just edited the post

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "all occurences of the second element." The second element in your example list is `('b',3)`.

Comment: What does `set()` do? Are `('a', 1)` and `('e', 1)` the same?

Comment: Anything with a repeating second element to be deleted I believe he means, so in this case, everything with `('_', 1)`

Comment: yeah thats what i meant

Comment: If there are other matching elements, as in if there were 3 1's and 2 7's, do you want the 7's removed as well? Or just the largest duplicate?

Comment: the 2 7's removed as well, so all duplicates removed

Comment: Do you want the first duplicate instance to stay? So as in the first '1', or do you want them all gone?

Comment: I want ALL of them gone, so the list would return unique tuples

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
a = [('a',1),('b',3),('c',1),('d',1),('e',5),('f',1)]

reduced = [y for x in a for y in x]

[x for x in a if reduced.count(x[0]) == 1 and reduced.count(x[1]) == 1]

# [('b', 3), ('e', 5)]
```

This flattens your original list of tuples into one list. It then iterates through the original list, and for each tuple it checks to see if either of its elements is in the flattened list only once. If so, it keeps it; otherwise, it discards it.

You can also use python dictionaries for this (if the first elements of the inner tuples are different from one another):

```
list({k:v for k,v in dict(a).items() if list(dict(a).values()).count(v)==1}.items())
```

The idea here is to convert your list of tuples into a dictionary and keep the `key-value` pairs where the `count` of the `value` part in the dictionary's `values` is 1.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, how about:

```
def UniqueTuples(tuples):
    seen, unique = set(), list()
    for x, y in tuples:
        if y not in seen:
            seen.add(y)
            unique.append((x, y))
    return unique
```